# Commit Application Settings Changes

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, application-settings

I'm [binding user settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h.aspx) to a bunch of controls on a WinForm dialog that has OK/Cancel buttons. While this works great to read in the bindings in, I would only like to commit binding changes if a user clicks OK, and not if they click cancel. Is there a simplistic setting to achieve this rather than managing all reading and committing myself?

Right now, let's say I have a textbox that binds to a user setting called "country". It has "United States" in it and if a user changes it to "Bolivia", that will get committed as soon as it is typed instead of when the OK button is pressed.

Comment: Is this C# or VB.NET?  Big difference.

Comment: @Hans Passant: it could be either.

Comment: It can't.  No way to compile C# code with the VB.NET IDE.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I don't think I understand what you're saying. You can bind user settings to controls in both C# and VB.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save settings, add in the ok button event handler:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

To reload the settings:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
```

Good luck!

Comment: So how does this override and not commit changes when binding settings to controls and changing a value?

Comment: The bound settings will be overwritten after validate the bound controls, the save method will commit the changes.